# storing multiple responses in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Im trying to create a script that will ask me to add a file path and store it, then keep asking me if I would like to store more until I say No. I then want it to ask me what Folder I would like to create and create that folder in all the previous file paths. the problem is that the dir array seems to only remember the latest entry? Here is what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash
x="1"
yn="y"
while [ "$yn" == "y" ]; do
read -p "Add a Directory" add
dir=("${dir[$x]}" "$add")
echo ${dir[$x]}
x=$(( $x + 1))
read -p "Do you want to add another directory?: " yn

done
```

while [ "$yn" == "y" ]; do
   read -p "What would you like to call the file?: " folderName
       #will create a loop that creats the directories using  dir array and the filename var.

```
read -p "Do you want to add another file to these directories? : " yn `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simpler form instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=()

while
    read -p "Add a Directory " add
    dir+=("$add")
    echo "$add"
    read -p "Do you want to add another directory?: " yn
    [[ $yn == [yY] ]]
do
    continue
done

# Do something with "${dir[@]}" e.g.

mkdir -p -- "${dir[@]}"
```

Also you can use `-e` to enable completion of pathnames. That would make it easier for you to specify your directories:

```
read -ep "Add a Directory " add
```

Note that I added `--` which would allow you to add directories with option-like filenames.

Update: You can also add a check:

```
while
    read -p "Add a Directory " add
    if [[ -n $add ]]; then
        echo "$add"
        dir+=("$add")
    else
        echo "Directory name is invalid."
    fi
    read -p "Do you want to add another directory?: " yn
    [[ $yn == [yY] ]]
do
    continue
done
```

For specifying one more parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=()

while
    read -p "Add a Directory " add
    dir+=("$add")
    echo "$add"
    read -p "Do you want to add another directory?: " yn
    [[ $yn == [yY] ]]
do
    continue
done

read -p "Folder name: " folder

fullpaths=("${dir[@]/%//$folder}")

mkdir -p -- "${fullpaths[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks works great. I see you placed the condition  for the while loop at the end of the loop and the do after the stuff to be done. These seems strange but works. what is the continue for?

Comment: @user2764736 It could actually be just `:` to do nothing. But I got used to using it there just to represent the concept that it would continue.

Comment: i have now added this to the code but only uses one of the file paths that i have entered. I need it to make the folder that i specified at the end of all the file paths I enter.        ` read -p "Folder Name: " fldName
mkdir -v  -p -- "${dir[@]}"/$fldName

Comment: How do you specify the folder, or enter the file paths? Which one is entered through the read prompt?

Comment: Great that script does exactly what I have been trying to do! Thanks I am very new at bash.

Comment: @user2764736 It replaces the ends of every entry with `/$foldername` and expands back to an array with replaced form. See shell parameter expansions: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: last question, what doe the /%// in fullpath actually mean or do? how do i prevent it from from making the folder in one with the same name already exists?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
dir=("${dir[$x]}" "$add")
```

You wanted to say:

```
dir=("${dir[@]}" "$add")
```

(Saying so would also obviate the need for the counter `x`.)